# Convert PDF to a bw image with sharp edges

Tags: image, imagemagick, converters

I need to convert many PDF pages to images, containing simple shapes such as rectangles or triangles. Texts and composed shapes consist of lines are also in the PDFs.

Example shape from a screenshot out of a PDF:

[image: Example Shape]

Note: The screenshot is unsharp because I've used Windows' print function in order to separate a single page. It seems to be that this function converts PDFs to images and then saves them as PDF file.

Requirements of images:

- sharp edges, a staircase is desired without any grey values
- lines of equal thickness
- relatively low resolution (<300 dpi would be wonderful)
- black & white only

I'd like to work with ImageMagick because it provides a lot of features. I guess anti-aliasing, black-threshold and sharpen are relevant to this, but I haven't reached my desired results.

[PDF example of a similar shape](https://eliza.infra.cloudconvert.com/download/~7f5e71cab71743f317e1caaca0359d986967c346c16ac0ff4832699fb821eac21e44e2e9534195caa3ed1c74)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
magick -density 288 -background white ~/Desktop/drawsvg.pdf -flatten -colorspace gray result.png
```

Comment: Prior to version 7, the command was `convert`, but it became `magick` at v7. Most material traditionally assumed a dpi of 72. By using an exact multiple such as 4, there should be fewer artefacts, roundings, misalignments... you can use 300 or other if you wish.

Comment: I believe it changed to `magick` to cause less command namespace pollution and to avoid clashing with `CONVERT.EXE` which is an unrelated Windows command to convert filesystems from FAT to NTFS format.

Comment: How can I avoid lines with different thickness?

Comment: Your sample PDF has disappeared. Please provide something that highlights any specific problems.